# Ajax Jquery Function response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am learning to use jQuery Ajax. What does `function(response)` mean and what is the meaning of `response == 1` and `response == 2`?

```js
jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
  if (response == 1) {
    $saveAlert.addClass('is-success').delay(900).fadeOut(700);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $tieBody.removeClass('has-overlay');
    }, 1200);
  } else if (response == 2) {
    location.reload();
  } else {
    $saveAlert.addClass('is-failed').delay(900).fadeOut(700);
    setTimeout(function() {
      $tieBody.removeClass('has-overlay');
    }, 1200);
  }
});
```

Comment: You call a PHP script which returns `1`, `2` or something else. Due to this return value JS do any action (show success message, error message or reload page).

Comment: The function is the handler for the callback. It's executed when the asynchronous request completes. `response` contains whatever value your endpoint has returned to you

Comment: could you give me an example

Comment: Take a look into the [jQuery api](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: @Alex In simple terms whatever your URL at your `ajaxurl` returns is saved in the `response` variable.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure what example I could give you that would be any different to the code in your question. I'd suggest reading the docs that Madhavan linked to.

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain the basics:

`jQuery.post` = You want to post some data to your endpoint

`ajaxurl` = your endpoint address. Typically a API

`data` = the data you want to send to your endpoint along with the request.

`function(response)` is where you handle the response from the endpoint.

So lets go through the code. First you call `post` to your endpoint / API with the `data` you want to post. Then you provide a callback (in your case a function) to handle the response the endpoint / API provides you.

In your case it looks like if the endpoint responds with `1`, you have successfully posted your data. If the endpoint responds with `2`, you have posted data and want to reload the site. If the endpoint does NOT respond with either `1` or `2`, it failed to post.

To help you understand the basics of jQuery post:

A well-written API / endpoint should respond with the correct HTTP status codes and status messages and it should be fairly easy to notice when data was posted correctly and when an error occurred.

I don't think your endpoint responds any good. `response == 1` or `response == 2`is not by any means clear and easy to understand.

A better way of handling success and errors is to use the `done` and `fail` handlers of jquery post (more on this below).

---

```
$.post( "test.php" );
```

This will completely ignore the response from calling the endpoint. I.e. you don't want to handle either success or error. PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS. You should handle success and error!

---

```
$.post( "test.php", function( data ) {
  //Do something now
});
```

This will do whatever you provide in the function when the endpoint has sent its response.

---

```
$.post( "example.php", function() {
  //You successfully reached the endpoint
  console.log( "success" );
})
  .done(function() {
    //Handle success here!
  })
  .fail(function() {
    //Handle error here
  })
```

This is probably the preferred way of handling both success and errors. It's pretty clear that if you reach the `fail`, it has failed. Both easy to read the code and easy to understand jquery post!

---

The examples above is copied from the jquery documentation.

Note that the previous handlers for `done` and `fail` was `success` and `error`, but `success` and `error` is deprecated and removed in jQuery 3.0!

So if you have jQuery version < 3.0 you need to find out if you need to use the new or old syntax, or if you need to update jQuery maybe?

Hope this explains enough to make you understand the basics, and to help you get further. I highly suggest you read the jQuery.post [documentation here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). I think you should also read the w3schools [documentation here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp).